# Java regex pattern matching to multiple of same tags

Tags: java, html, regex, xml

**Question:**

How do I successfully match `<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1><tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE</tag TAG1>` as 2 separate values?

**Background:**

I am attempting to match a string as such `<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1><tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE</tag TAG1>` 
Where `TAG1` is the name of that specific tag (multiple tags can have the same name but different values) and `SOME VALUE`, `ANOTHER VALUE` are different values enclosed by the tags.

So far I am able to match to one pair of tags as such `<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1>` using the regex pattern `<\\s*tag\\s*.+\\s*>(.*)</\\s*tag\\s*.+\\s*>`

The example above is a worst-case scenario with no characters separating the end of the first tag and the start of the second. My problem is when I run `find()` with my regex string, I get both tags as if they were one tag.

The problem is with the wildcard in between the tags `(.*)` because it doesn't exclude the end/start of a tag. I need the wildcard match because any character (including `\n`) could be inside the tags. I am also using `Pattern.DOTALL` to successfully match 1 tag with newlines inside.

Comment: As @R Nar mentions on this recent [python question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446964/simple-regex-for-simple-xml-string): [don't use regex to parse xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Its not necessarily XML, just a quick version for creating/reading input files given a template file. Everything works as expected now though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

```
String value = "<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1><tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE</tag TAG1>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<\\s*tag\\s*[^>]+\\s*>([^(</)]*)</\\s*tag\\s*[^>]+\\s*>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1>
<tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE</tag TAG1>
```

Comment: whoever down voted could you please tell me why to allow me to improve my answer?

Comment: A useful disclaimer might be to not use this for HTML/XML parsing as it won't work (Nested tags, properties, etc). My case was specific and Nested tags or tag properties were not going to exist so Regex worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue and this post helped me along. I spent some time understanding what @Nicolas Filotto did in his regex and it could be made simpler if you trust all tags formatting.

Answering the original question how to stop wildcard to match everything is to rather do a reverse match of what you are not looking for. Look for any character but tag end.

Pattern (without String escapes): `<tag TAG1>([^(<\/)]*)<\/tag TAG1>`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String regex = "<tag TAG1>([^(<\\/)]*)<\\/tag TAG1>";
String string = "<tag TAG1>SOME VALUE</tag TAG1><tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE</tag TAG1><tag TAG1>ANOTHER VALUE WITH \nNEWLINE</tag TAG1>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Base code generated from https://regex101.com